# How to plan database scheme to be query-able for filter matches?

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I'm planning the database scheme for a `Filter` document in MongoDB, and I was wondering how best to implement something like this.

Say I created a document with some of the fields contained in a [parsed URL object](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) which are either escaped regular expression strings or otherwise null.

Now, let's say I have a parsed URL object that I want to query the database with, and have the query return any `Filter` documents whose specified regular expressions match the query. Essentially a reverse regular expression match, if you will.

As requested, here's an example below:

```
var requestOptions = {
  protocol: 'https:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'nodejs.org',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'nodejs.org',
  hash: '#url_url_parsing',
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/docs/latest/api/url.html',
  path: '/docs/latest/api/url.html',
  href: 'https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parsing'
};
```

Let's say the database contains these documents:

```
{
  host: '*.org'
}

{
  hash: '#url_url_parsing'
}

{
  path: '/docs'
}

{
  port: 443
}

{
  protocol: 'http:'
}
```

Then the following code:

```
collection.find(requestOptions).toArray(function(err, docs) {...});
```

would ideally return:

```
[{
   host: '*.org'
 },

 {
   hash: '#url_url_parsing'
 }];
```

How could I do something equivalent to this? Or, if I'm thinking about this wrong, how should I be trying to achieve this? The point of the query is to determine whether a requested URL matches any of the specified filters in the database.

Comment: Some sample data and example would help us understand it better :)

Comment: @yaoxing I'm not really sure how to provide a better example since MongoDB can't really operate the way I described in the question. Basically I'm writing a web portal for a forward-proxy service and I wanted the portal to allow users to customize which requests made through the proxy would be logged and/or aborted (e.g. disallowing http requests for affiliate-ad domains). I was hoping for some advice how to approach database storage for filters so that querying could be optimized.

Comment: you can tell us what data you have, and how do you wish to filter these data, what kind of results are expected. then we can help with how to get the result using mongodb. or maybe it's not possible at all. It's just too abstract now.

Comment: @yaoxing sorry for the late reply, I've been busy, but I did add an example just now.